# How to open and append nested zip archives into dataframe without extracting?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, zip

I am trying to open a large number of csv files which found in several layers of zip files. Given the nature of this project, I am trying to open, read_csv them into a dataframe, append that data to an aggregate dataframe then continue through the loop.

Example: Folder Directory/First Zip/Second Zip/Third Zip/csv file.csv

My existing code can loop through the contents of the second and third zip file and get the name of each csv file. I am aware that this code can probably be made more simple by importing glob, but I'm unfamiliar.

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
import zipfile, re, io
directory = 'C:/Test/'
os.chdir(directory)
fname = "test" + ".zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(fname, 'r') as zfile:
    # second level of zip files
    for zipname in zfile.namelist():
        if re.search(r'\.zip$', zipname) != None:
            zfiledata = io.BytesIO(zfile.read(zipname))
            # third level of zip files
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata) as zfile2:
                for zipname2 in zfile2.namelist():
                    # this zipfile contains xml and csv contents. This filters out the xmls
                    if zipname2.find("csv") > 0:
                        zfiledata2 = io.BytesIO(zfile2.read(zipname2))
                        with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata2) as zfile3:
                            fullpath = directory + fname + "/" + zipname + "/" + zipname2 + "/"
                            # csv file names are always the same as their zips. this cleans the string.
                            csvf = zipname2.replace('_csv.zip',".csv")
                            filehandle = open(fullpath, 'rb')
                            # the above statement is erroring: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
                            zfilehandle = zipfile.ZipFile(filehandle)
                            data = []
                            csvdata = StringIO.StringIO(zfilehandle.read(csvf))
                            df = pd.read_csv(csvdata)
                            data.append(df)
print(data.head())
```

Comment: Maybe try to build a recursive function with the same code instead?

Comment: I know a recursive function would be more efficient, but im not sure that it would help at all with the error Im experiencing on filehandle = open(fullpath, 'rb')